# Changing status to reserved on selection

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database called 'place' that has the lists of all places for hire and then another column with the status of the hall. Example 'Available' or 'Reserved'

I've created a drop-down menu where only the places that have the status 'available' will appear and can be selected and this can be stored in a separate table called Bookings - which works fine. 
My next step is to create a query where once someone has selected the 'available' place and it is stored in the Bookings table, the status in the 'place' table changes to 'Reserved'. However i'm slightly confused as to how to go about this and would be extremely grateful for some feedback or guidance.

Here is my current code of the dropdown menu that is part of my form:

```
$placeSQL="SELECT place from Place WHERE Status='Available'"; 
$exeplaceSQL=mysql_query($placeSQL);


echo "<select name=p_place>";
while($place = mysql_fetch_array($exeplaceSQL))
{
echo"<option value=".$place['place'].">".$place['place']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

EDIT: Insert query:

```
$placeName=$_POST['p_place'];

$name=$_POST['c_name'];
$Sname=$_POST['c_sname'];

if (!$name or !$Sname or !$placeName)
{
    echo "<p>Your form is incomplete ";
    }
else
{
$booking="insert into Bookings(Name, SName, placeName) values ('".$name."','".$Sname."','".$placeName."')";
$exebooking=mysql_query($booking);

echo "Thank you for hiring  with us";
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? You don't know how to write the `update` query? You don't know when to run it? The code that inserts into the `Bookings` table would be more relevant here than the code that you're showing now.

Comment: Using [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) mysql_* extensions in the year 2014 is a very bad idea. Take a look at the successors [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). No support from my side...

Comment: Where would I place my update query? in the 'bookings' page where my code that inserts is placed or on the page of the form? I'll upload that code now, sorry about the confusion

Comment: Example: `UPDATE table SET column='$var' WHERE column='$something'` --- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would I need to define my column as a variable?  Also where would I place this update code? on the same page that my form is on or on my bookings page? Sorry about the daft questions im new to PHP and teaching myself!

Comment: It will depend on what data is in your column. I'm sure that there are more than one "place", yes?. Give an example of what you have in regards to that. Say like "seat_01", "seat_02" etc. or whatever is in your DB.

Comment: When a place is selected from the dropdown it saves to the new table from the old  perfectly as does the 'date' drop down. The only issue is the column 'status' of the place. This column is in my database table but isnt part of my form. After this SQL query that I have posted above I attempted to make an update query underneath but it seems to be going horrible wrong